# Regarding Profile Pictures of Facebook Friends

Tags: unity, facebook, leaderboards

Background: I am creating a Leaderboard of Facebook friends in unity.

Question: Can we download and save the images of Facebook Friends on the device of the user for the purpose of reuse? I would like to store the images of the FBFriends on the user's device so that there is no need to download the same pictures everytime the game is restarted. Is it legal to do so?

I asked the same question in Facebook Developers forums but I did not get any response. Kindly guide me. How do devs build a leaderboard of Facebook friends normally?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is desirous, in fact, to reduce bandwidth usage across the board. However, you may want to refresh them occasionally in case the user changes their profile picture, and I would make sure the cache doesn’t grow to large by deleting images that are not currently on the leaderboard and/or haven’t been used recently.

As for how others do it, well, I keep a very short lived cache which is cleared on every launch.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response mate. Do we need to get any permission from the players in the game terms of service or something before saving the images on device? Is it okay to cache 75 images of 120x120 on device?

Comment: You could ask if you wanted to, but no, that’s not necessary. You’re just cashing data for better performance. You don’t need special permission to do that. As for the size of that cache, my gut instinct says you don’t have to worry about 75 120x120 images, but it’s really up to you how much space you want to take up on the user’s device.

Comment: Alright brother. Thanks alot for this information. This helps alot.

Comment: Thanks alot man. I have completed the friends leaderboard. However Can I do the same with Daily Leaderboard? Can I save the images of players on disc that are not his/her friends?

Comment: Every browser does it when caching facebook.com visits. Google does it when crawling. Archive.org does it when saving copies of the site. You don’t need to worry about these.

Comment: Phew!. This was giving me mad tension. Couldnt find the answer anywhere. Thanks alot Ed man. Really!